# What does 'principle' mean in 'reasons of principle'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is the heading for http://www.bbc.co.uk/ethics/torture/ethics/wrong_1.shtml. How do you determine/deduce the right [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/principle) for this noun? Which of the following is it?

> 1(.0). A fundamental truth or proposition that serves as the foundation for a system of belief or behaviour or for a chain of reasoning

This means that 'reasons of principle' are just the norm and standard, so they should hold, regardless of their truth, falsity, merit or demerit.

> 1.2. [mass noun] Morally correct behaviour and attitudes

This means that 'reasons of principle' are reasons, consistent with and due to morality or rectitude.

Answer (score 2):

Both definitions are correct.  Notice that this idiom uses "principle" as a mass noun, consistent with the second definition.  Also notice that "morally correct behaviour and attitudes" can be part of a "system of belief or behavior", and the result of a "chain of reasoning" from a "fundamental truth or proposition".  The definitions are therefore compatible.  The usage example gives no reason to choose between them.

Comment: +1. It is very common that _several_ dictionary definitions apply at once, and it is a futile exercise to try and determine for every word in every sentence which _exact_ dictionary definition matches best, if only because there are few dictionaries that would agree on all these details.

Answer (score -1):

Principle refer to a statement of fundamental truth which reflects a phenomena based on cause and effect relationship